# GWT RPC call not working when I change the endpoint

Tags: gwt, rpc

I have a simple RPC call that works fine when it is calling into the local server

```
      ContactsServiceAsync rpcService = GWT.create(ContactsService.class);

      rpcService.getContactDetails(new AsyncCallback<ArrayList<ContactDetails>>() {
      public void onSuccess(ArrayList<ContactDetails> result) {
          Window.alert("Successfully called server");
      }

      public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        Window.alert("Error calling server");
      }
    });
```

What I now want to do is change the endpoint to call a service on GAE ( I just deployed the same GWT app on GAE so the service name should remain unchanged )

```
  ContactsServiceAsync rpcService = GWT.create(ContactsService.class);

  ServiceDefTarget target = (ServiceDefTarget) rpcService;
  target.setServiceEntryPoint("http://myquizapp2.appspot.com/");


  rpcService.getContactDetails(new AsyncCallback<ArrayList<ContactDetails>>() {
      public void onSuccess(ArrayList<ContactDetails> result) {
          Window.alert("Successfully called server");
      }

      public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        Window.alert("Error calling server");
      }
    });
```

Note the "attempt" I made to change the end point the client will use to call the service. It does not work and my onFailure method gets called.  Am I attempting to do something that does not make any sense or can it be done at all?

Comment: You are hitting cross domain rpc issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at how to achieve cross domain GWT RPC. You can start of with some example here http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-do-cross-domain-gwt-rpc